# Build is successful but Archive throwing GoogleDataTransport Error. xcode12

Tags: ios, swift, archive, ipa, xcode12

i'm able to build the app sucessfully but archive is throwing the below error.
Xcode Version: 12.3
Tried Observations:

1. BuildSettings >> Architectures >> ExludeArchitecture >> arm64
2. Quoted included Header Framework Set to NO.
3. Deleted Derived Data
   rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
   pod deintegrate
   pod update
   Reference
   [Full Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT6Zg.png)
   podfile as a reference [Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYudZ.png)

Comment: did you try making pod update, can you share your podfile as well ?

Comment: @zeytin added pod file can you please look into it.